# Javascript add class active when click a link after load another page?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a list `a.href` to many URL contain film.
When I click `a.href`, it will reload my page. I don't know how to add the class `.active` to the `a.href` current selected.

In Ajax call, it simple like this code, it's working because the page is not reloaded. But I write on PHP and using `$_GET` and `$_POST` method. So the page must be reloaded.

Have any method to add the class `.active` on `a.href` link was clicked?

```
<div class="btn-group listEp col-md-12">
    $i = 0;
    <a href="#" style="opacity: 1;" class="btn btn-success disabled">Episode:</a>
    <?php foreach($data['episodes'] as $epList) { ?>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo $epList['href']); ?>"> <?php echo $i++; ?> </a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
$(function() {
    $('#listEp').on("click", "a", function() {  
        $( "#listEp a:first-child" ).css("cssText", "background: #4CAF50 !important;");
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: How does a href to one episode look like, whats the value of `$epList['href']`?
Generally something like this will work: `<a class="btn btn-default <? if($ifActive) {echo "active";} ?>" href="...`   You just need to find a way to chech if it is active, probably by comparing `$_GET` and `$epList['href']`

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply like this,

```
$('a.btn[href]').click(function(){
    $('a.btn[href]').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

above code removes active class from other same elements and adds class in this element.
Add below code to that page which is rendering on reload,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.active.btn[href]').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this added class `active` be gone once the new page is loaded?

Comment: all code in one `index.php` file. I added exactly your code in my `index.php` file but nothing any change.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reload page after click and create a custom action on this just do this:

```
$('#listEp').on("click", "a", function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault() // this will disable default action which is redirect in case of a element
    e.stopPropagation() // this will stop element beeing propagated by other functions

    $( "#listEp a:first-child" ).css("cssText", "background: #4CAF50 !important;");
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: No, ii's must reload the page after a click. Your solution isn't working because it gets URL of a.href and change.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're targeting an ID which doesn't exist, the element has a class `listEp`. Try `$('.listEp')` instead